# Calculating standard deviation returning more than one data

Tags: java, standard-deviation

I'm trying to calculate standard deviation of wifi rssi value. I scan data for 30 seconds and then calculate it's standard deviation like this:

```
        for (int length = 0; length < resultsData.size(); length++) {

            double sum = 0;
            double sd = 0;
            for (int l = 0; l < resultsData.get(length).values.size(); l++) {
                sum += resultsData.get(length).values.get(l);

            }

            double average = sum / resultsData.get(length).values.size();
            sd += (Math.pow((sum-average), 2));
            double SD = Math.sqrt(sd/resultsData.get(length).values.size()-1);


            positionData.addValue(resultsData.get(length).getRouter(), average);
            Log.v("SD", String.valueOf(SD));
        }
```

Why the result is more than one? Here's the log

```
V/SD: 178.67550857247704
    180.76127985287263
    258.6297016598155
    342.92879445720627
    351.79322190907664
    258.45588877709247
    358.5719004995616
    369.1744470855485
    313.72831287322157
    371.78163032237256
V/SD: 273.05616515593147
    216.67267940374947
    288.8982519850198
```

Comment: Do you mean, why is more than one line printed?  If that's the case, look at where your log statement is.

Comment: Btw, you could assign  the result of `resultsData.get(length).values` and use that to make your code more readable and also a little more performant (depends on the type of `resultsData`). Additionally both loops could be replaced by a foreach, i.e. `for(List<Double> dataset : resultsData)` (outer loop) and `for(Double value : dataset)` (inner loop). Further, that `double sd = 0; ... sd += ...` could be replaced by `double sd = Math.pow(...);` because you're only ever adding _one_ value to `sd` (unless that's not what you want).

Comment: I need to add all value, not just one.

Comment: I've try to calculate with calculator and it shouldn't more than 10 this is data look like ```-30,-32,-33,-35,-33,-34,-33,-33,-34,-31```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you're asking why it prints to the log more than once? If so, I would assume it is because 
`Log.v("SD", String.valueOf(SD));` 
is located **inside** of the first `for loop`. If you want everything to finish running and then run the log statement once at the end, move it outside of the `for loop`. Hope this helps!

Comment: SD turns red when i move it outside for

Comment: That's because 'SD' was created as a local variable in the 'for loop'. You could create 'SD' before the for loop starts like 'double SD;' Then just take off 'double' before SD in the loop where you set its value.

Comment: Is my calculation code correct? Why the value is > 100?

Comment: It really depends on all of the inputs, are you able to post the input numbers to verify?